# Evaluating Indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I have the question: Evaluate

$$\frac{9^{1/3} \cdot 27^{-1/2}}{3^{-1/6} \cdot 3^{-2/3}}$$

I have use the rules of indices to get (cuberoot 9 X 1/squareroot 27) / (sixthroot 3 X 1/cuberoot 3^2) and the answer I get is 0.2.

However, the solutions say that the answer should be 1 and I do not understand why.

Comment: Please format and parenthesize appropriately.

Comment: At 177 rep and with 30 questions posted, you should know [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) by now. This is illegible.

Comment: Wat do u mean by the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

\begin{align}
\frac{9^{1/3} \cdot 27^{-1/2}}{3^{-1/6} \cdot 3^{-2/3}} =\frac{(3^2)^{1/3} \cdot (3^3)^{-1/2}}{3^{-1/6-2/3} }=\frac{3^{2/3} \cdot 3^{-3/2}}{3^{-5/6} }=3^{2/3-3/2}\cdot 3^{5/6}=3^{-5/6}\cdot 3^{5/6}=1.
\end{align}